# How to access other methods in a django class?

Tags: django, csv

I'm just learning Python and Django.

What I want to do is something like this

```
csvobject = CSVViewer(file)
rows = csvobject.get_row_count()
```

This is what I have so far. Remember this is all new to me so I'm looking for a an explanation. Thanks.

```
class CSVViewer:


    def __init__(self, file=None):
        self.file = file

    def read_file(self):
        data = []
        file_read = csv.reader(self.file)
        for row in file_read:
            data.append(row)
        return data


    def get_row_count(self):
        return len(read_file(self))
```

I am having problems with `read_file(self)`

Comment: self.read_file() .. not sure why this got a vote to close  ...

Comment: Explain why vote to close? It's clear whats being ask here, I cannot access read_file(self) in my get_row_count method, why?

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but the main issue is probably that you didn't post a traceback of your error, just saying "I am having problems...". In any case, change it to `self.read_file`.

Comment: I also covered, explaining the issue and what I have tried so far. All makes a good question to me.

Comment: thats David Robinson, why not self.read_file()?

Comment: you need to call it like `self.read_file()` not `read_file(self)` ..alternativelt you could call it as `CSVViewer.read_file(self)`

Comment: @Joran Beasley i did try that and got unresolved reference file_read etc. I just assumed it was my flawed understanding.

Comment: ok, I get it now. you have to reference self and not repass self!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, It seems you're missing `import csv` in order to `csv.reader(self.file)` works in the `def read_line(self)` method.
Second, you must call the instance method `read_file` like this `self.read_file()` in the `get_row_count` method. This should work:

```
import csv

class CSVViewer:


    def __init__(self, file=None):
        self.file = file

    def read_file(self):
        data = []
        file_read = csv.reader([self.file])
        for row in file_read:
            data.append(row)
        return data


    def get_row_count(self):
        return len(self.read_file())
```